# Does the following integral exist

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $(F_n : n ∈ \mathbb{N})$ be an increasing sequence in $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ and $f$ be a measurable function defined on $\cup_{n∈\mathbb{N}}F_n$. Suppose $f$ is integrable on $F_n$ for every $n∈\mathbb{N}$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{F_n}{f}dλ$ exists in $\mathbb{R}$. Does $\int_{\cup_{n∈\mathbb{N}}F_n}f dλ$ exist?

So far, I have used a definition I found online: Let $\delta>0$, $F_n=F$, and $\forall n>0$: $\int_F{|f_n|<\epsilon}$, whenever $\mu(F)<\delta$. Then using this definition: $\int_{\cup_{n=1}^{M}F}|f_n|\leq \sum_{n=1}^{M}{\int_F{|f_n|}} \leq \sum_{n=1}^{M} \epsilon = \epsilon M$. So, I guess the integral exists but I'm not sure. I might be completely wrong but that's my only solution so far. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Look at the two cases :
- If $\lambda(\bigcup_{m=1}^\infty F_m)<\infty$


- If $\lambda(\bigcup_{m=1}^\infty F_m)=+\infty$

Comment: @EDX Finiteness of the measure space will not help here . For example if $f=\frac{1}{x^{3}}$ and $F_{n}=[-1,-\frac{1}{n}]\cup[\frac{1}{n},1]$ . Then $F_{n}$'s are increasing and $\lambda(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} F_{n})=2$ and you have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{F_{n}}f\,d\lambda =0 $ . But $\int_{\bigcup F_{n}} f = \int_{[-1,1]\setminus\{0\}} \frac{1}{x^{3}}\,d\lambda$ is not integrable

Answer (score 1):

It's not true in general.

Let $F_{n}=[-n,n]$ and let $f(x)=x$ . Then $\int_{F_{n}} f\,d\lambda= 0$ for all $n$  and hence the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{F_{n}} f\,d\lambda =0$ .

Now $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}F_{n}=\mathbb{R}$ but $x$ is not integrable over the real line.

However it's true if $f$ is non-negative. In that case let $g_{n}=f\cdot\mathbf{1}_{F_{n}}$ .

Then $g_{n}$ is an increasing sequence of non-negative measurable functions and $\lim_{n\to\infty} g_{n}= f\cdot\mathbf{1}_{\{\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} F_{n}\}}$ .

So By Monotone Convergence Theorem you get your required result as $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{F_{n}}f\,d\lambda=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\Bbb{R}} g_{n}\,d\lambda = \int_{\Bbb{R}} f\cdot\mathbf{1}_{\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}F_{n}}\,d\lambda = \int_{\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}F_{n}}f\,d\lambda$